# calling a different function behind the same button click event of dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have changed the content of the buttons if the entry is deleted then it is replace by restore. but the function call or the button click event executed behind is the delete function. 
I want to execute the restore function behind the restore button.

Following is my code:

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button  Name="btnDelete" 
                            Click="BtnDelete_Click">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Delete" />

                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding deleted}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"  />


                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding deleted}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"  />
                                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Restore"></Setter>

                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is how the UI looks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack to your problem is use of button `Content` property in code behind.

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button = (Button)sender;
   if (button.Content.ToString() == "Delete")
   {
      //Do delete stuff
   }
   else
   {
      //Do restore stuff
   }
}
```